# Create EC2 instance and get public IP when available

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have a monotonous work of creating an ec2 instance from an AMI and then ssh into it and run a crypto bot to get a sub domain SSL certificates for it and then run some frontend and backend onto it.

I would like to automate this...

I am able to create the EC2 instance

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0bef9cfcxxxxxx --count 1 --instance-type t2.medium --key-name MyKey --security-group-ids SG-1 --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=SubDomain}]'
```

but how do I wait till the instance is UP and get the public IP for the next steps?

Any suggestions would help,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the target instance id, you can query your instance and get the current state, instanceId, name (assuming you tagged them with a name) and public IP via something like:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --instance-ids YOUR_TARGET_INSTANCE_ID \
    --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[State.Name, InstanceId, Tags[?Key==\`Name\`]|[0].Value, PublicIpAddress]" \
    --output text
```

You could run this query in a loop until the status comes back as running and then capture the public ip address:

```
while :
do
    output=$(aws ec2 describe-instances \
       --instance-ids YOUR_TARGET_INSTANCE_ID \
       --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[State.Name, InstanceId, \
           Tags[?Key==\`Name\`]|[0].Value, PublicIpAddress]" \
       --output text)
   
    if [[ "${output}" == running* ]] ; then 
        cut -d $'\t' -f4- <<<"${output}"
        break
    fi 
done
```

Note:

1. The `aws ec2` queries are all using the default AWS profile. You can specify a different profile via   `--profile your_target_profile_name` if needed.
2. If you do not know your target instance id, you can remove the `--instance-id` portion of the `aws ec2` query and list all of your instances (in your default region). You could choose the required instance id from that list.